# Not able to use password protected zip file in Cocos2dx

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

While running the project, Xcode is not able to fetch the images from the password protected zip file in cocos2dx V.3.16. Have attached the screesnhots for reference.

I need to use the password protected zip file for resources of my cocos2dx project.

Please help.??

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKlmR.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0SKX.png)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKuvr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just extract these zips, and zip them again? (You must have already known the password).